# Is there a way to add the Developer Powershell for VS 2019 as an integrated terminal in VSCode?

Tags: powershell, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, cmd, cl

I'm working on a project that requires me to compile C++ code using MSVC, but I am working mostly with VSCode. As such, I was wondering if there is a way for me to add the Developer Powershell as an integrated terminal, so that I can compile without needing a secondary terminal open. I thought of just opening VSCode from the Developer PS itself, but since this is mostly a temporary project it seemed like a lot of repetitive work. I tried using the `Shell launcher` extension for VSCode but it didn't work. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal act like the `Developer PowerShell for VS 2019` console that comes with Visual Studio 2019, add the following to your Visual Studio Code `settings.json` file (`> Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`):

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:/Windows/SysWOW64/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe"
```

and

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": "-noe -c Import-Module 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'; Enter-VsDevShell ed9e071d"
```

Note that a *32-bit* version of PowerShell is started, followed by import of a module and a call to a function from that module.

I've taken (and adapted) the commands - whose details may differ depending on the Visual Studio version - from the Properties dialog of the following shortcut file (`*.lnk`):

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2019\Visual Studio Tools\Developer PowerShell for VS 2019.lnk
```

Comment: Is there a way to open a 64 bit version of the development tools as well? I tried looking around for it but there doesn't seem to be a clear way...

Comment: @Carmo If you replace `SysWOW64` with `System32`, you'll get a 64-bit PowerShell session - but I can't tell you whether everything will work as intended - do let us know.

Comment: It seems to start a powershell session, but the tools seem to be x64_86 tools.

Answer (score 6):

A variation of the answer of mklement0 is to use `terminal.integrated.profiles.windows` in the Visual Studio Code `settings.json` like this:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Developer PowerShell for VS 2019": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "path": "{env:windir}\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
            "args": [
                "-noe",
                "-c",
                "&{Import-Module 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'; Enter-VsDevShell 7068d947}"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: path is unnecessary since you already have  "source": "PowerShell". Doing this also allows you to use powershell 7

Answer (score 4):

I found this in March of 2023, looking for an answer to this question. At this point, Microsoft [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022#developer-powershell) a `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1` script that is the recommended way to start a developer PowerShell terminal. I tried simply making that script the `path` parameter in the above JSON, but that didn't work. Then I tried making it the sole member of `args`, and that seemed to work briefly and then exit. Finally, I added `-NoExit` and that seems to work like a charm!

Of note for anyone coming after me, I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 with an x86-64 install (so it's under `C:\Program Files\`.

```json
        "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": [
                "-NoExit",
                "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/Tools/Launch-VsDevShell.ps1"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Update for Visual studio 2022 on my machine

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "args": [
            "-noe",
            "-c",
            "&{Import-Module 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'; Enter-VsDevShell ed9e4c07}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow up question, can I get it to start in the workspace root with these options?

Comment: @EduardoSerna Kind of. You can add `-WorkingDirectory C:\\Users\\eduar\\path\\to\\repo` as another argument (or two), but then it's hardcoded to that path. I haven't been able to find a way to get it to just automatically go to the workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on all answers here to make it behave a little more as expected. Add this to your settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": [
                "-WorkingDirectory",
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "-NoExit",
                "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/Common7/Tools/Launch-VsDevShell.ps1",
                "-SkipAutomaticLocation"
            ]
        }
    },
```

The `-WorkingFolder ${workspaceFolder}` and `SkipAutomaticLocation` will make the terminal start in your current workspace.

The `"overrideName": true` will override the default `pwsh` name in the list of terminals once it's opened  and name it `Developer PowerShell for VS 2022`:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to dynamically get the Visual Studio installation directory unfortunately so everyone will have to put in their absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with Windows style paths on my machine and I have only installed Build Tools so the path is changed as well.
My settings.json looks like this now:

```
"Developer PowerShell for VS 2022": {
    "overrideName": true,
    "source": "PowerShell",
    "icon": "terminal-powershell",
    "args": [
        "-NoExit",
        "& \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\Launch-VsDevShell.ps1\"",
    ]
}
```

Additionally I had to change the Execution-Policy for PS scripts:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

Execute in Admin Powershell at your own risk.